# excel vba working with worksheetfunction

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I just have a quick question about implementing worksheetfuncion across multiple sheets. I don't quite understand why my code produces application defined or object defined error in this line

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(14, 6)))
```

a portion of my code is shown below

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer, lastcoln As Integer
Dim rowht As Double
Dim count As Integer, total As Integer

lastrow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Row - 1 + Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.count
lastcoln = Sheet2.UsedRange.Column - 1 + Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.count

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Legend" And ws.Name <> "Master Schedule" Then
lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
ws.Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = "Total Crew Count: " & lastrow - 1
For j = 6 To lastcoln

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(14, 6)))

Next j
End If
Next ws
```

Thank you for any help. greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question itself isn't a duplicate, but the same answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

Change `count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(14, 6)))` to `count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 6), ws.Cells(14, 6)))`